# When using RSA algorithm, is it a risk if plaintext and its ciphertext are identical? if yes why?

Tags: encryption, rsa

Is it a risk if RSA produce exactly same ciphertext for the given plaintext?

Comment: Only if it happens more often than would be expected by random chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA encryption with a 1024-bit public key encrypts messages up to 117 bytes, and the corresponding ciphertext has length 128 bytes. More generically, for all key sizes and with standard [PKCS#1](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125) padding modes, the ciphertext is always longer than the plaintext. Thus, they cannot be equal to each other.

If you consider post-padding input (i.e. the 128-byte string which goes under exponentiation) then a fixed point (a number which goes unchanged through the exponentiation) *may* expose parts of the private key; however, you will not hit it by chance. Or, rather, you will hit it only with negligible probability (you can *force* it if you wish, but nobody can prevent you from revealing your own private key anyway). An attacker gains no extra information by such a random occurrence, because such an equality can already be tested by the attacker... so the answer is: no, there is no risk in that.

Comment: Nothing about PKCS#1 padding forces the result to be different than the input. For example the first 11 bytes of the result may be zero, so the remaining 117 bytes could be equal to the input: a fixed point is possible. But as you said, the probability is negligible.

Comment: @GregS: ah, that's the difference between equal _as sequences of bytes_ (`Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[])` in Java) and equal _as integers_ (`BigInteger.equal()` in Java).

Comment: Every RSA key has a number of values that encrypt to the plaintext, i.e. are unconcealed.

Specifically, there are (gcd(e−1,p−1)+1)(gcd(e−1,q−1)+1) of these values.

Answer (score 2):

You should only ever use the RSA algorithm on (a) randomly-generated session keys used for a symmetric cipher (b) cryptographic hash functions used as part of a signature mechanism.

For your point specifically, see page 290 of [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (Chapter 8 :)

One supremely nice benefit of using RSA only on random and indistinguishable-from-random inputs is that you're never at risk of ciphertext being interpreted as plaintext.

Using RSA on data directly is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is extremely rare. There are (gcd(e−1,p−1)+1)(gcd(e−1,q−1)+1) of these values for every RSA key.